# What is it called when a star or candle changes its intensity at random?

Tags: definition

Is there a word given to the phenomenon that occurs when the intensity of a candle or star fluctuates at random?

Comment: Maybe the candle/star is *glittering* or *twinkling*.

Comment: Candles *flicker*. Stars *twinkle*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A star, as seen from Earth, is said to *twinkle*.

> Twinkle, twinkle little star...

A candle will *flicker*.

> I see the candle flicker in the window.

They are somewhat interchangeable but these parings are the most common.

Comment: +1 for the most common words, but to add some detail: small points of lights that vary in intensity quickly *twinkle* (e.g. stars, the skyline of a distant city); lights of all sizes can *flicker* at all speeds (e.g. matches, campfires, fluorescent lamps, a distant bushfire). Additionally, to *sparkle* is to emit flashes of bright light, whereas to *glimmer* is to glow with an unsteady dim light, as of dying coals in a fire. *Shimmer* and *glitter* usually indicate reflected light, the former especially from a wet surface and the latter from a faceted one.

Comment: If you like long words the term for a star is scintillation.